# redis-server process keeps restarting when killed on macOS

Tags: mac-osx, redis, launchd

I am trying to kill the `redis-server` process on macOS. Whenever I kill it or shut it down, it restarts under a different process id.

I've tried killing it three ways:

1. `redis-cli shutdown`
2. `sudo kill [proc-id]` : It's running as `root` for whatever reason, so `sudo` is needed.
3. `brew services stop redis`

I checked `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` and `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/` for an applicable plist but none of the files contain `redis`, case insensitive search.

I also checked the "Users & Groups" section of the macOS control panel and do not see any entries under "Login Items" that are applicable.

The macOS console app reveals something interesting when I kill the process:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.redis.redis-server): Service only ran for 8 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 2 seconds`
```

So it seems that it's registered and being watchdogged by launchd, but I can't figure out where the configuration is for the life of me.

`launchctl list|grep -i redis` does not reveal any results, either.

Thoughts?

Comment: If it's running as root, it's a launch daemon not a launch agent, which means you need to use `sudo launchctl` to control it. Try `sudo launchctl list org.redis.redis-server` and `sudo launchctl disable org.redis.redis-server`

Comment: @GordonDavisson `list` revealed a result. Running `sudo launchctl disable system/org.redis.redis-server` and `sudo launchctl stop org.redis.redis-server` seems like it should have worked, but the process is still running and it still restarts after killing it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson same issue sudo launchctl disable org.redis.redis-server returns unrecognized target specifier.. error